# http-conduit-downloader: discrepancy in ghci behaviour vs executable behaviour

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I'm experiencing some weird GHC behaviour. Using *http-conduit-downloader*, I'm making secure connections to a web server successfully. Data is downloaded correctly when using *cabal repl*. However, when running a test executable built off this code, all of my requests return `DRError "Connection failed"`.

I'm sure I'm not accidentally building against the wrong version of the code. Is there perhaps a GHC flag that I'm missing that might be affecting the runtime behaviour, that cabal repl uses automatically?

GHC v7.8.3

http-conduit-downloader v1.0.21

Thanks for the help.

P.S. this problem came about as a workaround for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471020/haskell-tls-error-with-http-conduit

Comment: After a little more testing, I've filed a bug report: [link](https://github.com/bazqux/http-conduit-downloader/issues/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maintainer noted the solution in reply to the [bug report you filed](https://github.com/bazqux/http-conduit-downloader/issues/4):

> This is because of missing `-threaded` flag that seems to be required for HOpenSSL (and HTTPS sites).
>   Add `ghc-options: -threaded` [to the Cabal file].